# Array of linked lists added to from directory

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, dirent.h

I've been trying to create an array of linked lists. The array being size 26 each part corresponding to a letter of the alphabet. The user inputs a directory of the PC and the name of any folders or files in that directory are then added to the a linked list in the array based on what letter they start with.

How i've been trying to do it->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

My node and its declaration:

```
struct node{
       char data[50];
       struct node *next;
};

struct node* nodeArray[26];
```

My alphabet:

```
const char* basis[26] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
```

A string comparing function to check which linkedlist in the array my word goes(compares to alphabet)

```
int StartsWith(const char *a, const char *b)
{
   if(strncasecmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Where I add the node and also where the problem is(the printf("1") is there to stop my computer from basically crashing):

```
void addNode(struct node **q,const char *d){
        if(((*q)->data)==NULL){
            *q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            strncpy((*q)->data,d,50);
            (*q)->next = NULL;
        } else {
            (*q)->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            *q = (*q)->next;
            printf("1");
            addNode(q,d);
            }
}
```

The function that calls addNode, directory is a computer directory that's already been checked to exist:

```
void returner(char* directory){
    int i;
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    char* tempD;
    dp = opendir (directory);
    struct node **z;

    while ((ep = readdir(dp))){
              tempD = (char*)malloc(50);
        if ( !strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(ep->d_name, "..") ){

        } else {
            strncpy(tempD, ep->d_name, 50);
            for(i=0; i<26 ; i++){
                if(StartsWith(tempD, basis[i])){
                    z = &nodeArray[i];
                    addNode(z,tempD);
                    print();
                }
            }
        }
        free(tempD);
    }
closedir (dp);
}
```

Print function:

```
void print(){
    int i;
    struct node *temp;

    for(i=0 ; i < 26; i++){
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = nodeArray[i];
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
}
```

The program seems fine when adding the first node to a spot on the array such as "aaa.txt" "bbb.txt" "ccc.txt" "ddd.txt", but once a second is attempted to be added like a "ccd.txt" after a "ccc.txt" exists when it keeps going forever or until the pc crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the right value in your `addNode` for finding the list insertion point.

Pointer-to-pointer enumeration through a linked list is frequently used to walk from the head pointer to the last `next` pointer in the list, each time holding the *address* of the said-pointer. When you reach one that is `NULL` (which will be `head` in the case of an empty list), you stop, and you can use your pointer-to-pointer via dereference to assign your new node address.

If you want to insert on the tail, the way to do it would be something like this:

```
#define DATA_MAX_LEN    50

void addNode(struct node **q,const char *d)
{
    // assumes a null-terminated linked list
    while (*q)
        q = &(*q)->next;

    *q = malloc( sizeof **q );

    // ensures truncation and termination
    strncpy((*q)->data,d,DATA_MAX_LEN-1);
    (*q)->data[ DATA_MAX_LEN-1] = 0;

    // make sure we terminate the list at our new node
    (*q)->next = NULL;
}
```

Invoked from your updated `returner` function like this:

```
void returner(char* directory)
{
    DIR *dp = opendir (directory);
    if (dp)
    {
        struct dirent *ep;
        while ((ep = readdir(dp)))
        {
            // skip parent and self symbolic links
            if (ep->d_name[0] == '.' && (ep->d_name[1] == 0 || (ep->d_name[1] == '.' && ep->d_name[2] == 0)))
                continue;

            for(int i=0; i<26 ; i++)
            {
                if(StartsWith(ep->d_name, basis[i]))
                    addNode(nodeArray+i, ep->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir (dp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot this works perfectly!  This is the first time doing something like this in C so I think i just went too far into it as I tried to fix it and ended up making it more complicated in the process.

Comment: @SeanM you were closer to good than most people usually are the first time they try pointer-to-pointer work in C. Anyway, glad it helped. Best of luck.

Comment: @SeanM probably should have mentioned this too: You have a memory leak in your `print` function. That `malloc` line has no business being there. This isn't Java or C#.

Comment: Yea someone else commented that and deleted their comment, so I got that part fixed. Thanks anyway though.